# Why Convert IRemoteFunction Interface Error ? How to Do?

Tags: go

Why Convert IRemoteFunction Interface Error ?  How to Do ? My go version 1.15. I Want Interface to Execute Some Code .Why Convert IRemoteFunction Interface Error ?

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type IRemoteFunction interface {
    SetTenantCode(str string)
    GetTenantCode() string
}

type THelloWorld struct {
    Tenantid string
}

func (T *THelloWorld) SetTenantCode(str string) {
    T.Tenantid=str
}

func (T *THelloWorld) GetTenantCode() string {
    return T.Tenantid
}


func main() {
    objectmap:=make(map[string]reflect.Type)
    t := reflect.TypeOf((*THelloWorld)(nil)).Elem()
    objectmap[strings.ToLower("test")] = t
    objinf:=reflect.New(objectmap[strings.ToLower("test")]).Elem().Interface()
    obj2,isok:= objinf.(IRemoteFunction)
    if isok{ // isok===false 
        fmt.Println(obj2)
        fmt.Println("Obj is IRemoteFunction ") // ??? ``
    }   else { // ``
        // ++ why isok==false ?
        fmt.Println("Obj is not IRemoteFunction ")  
     }

}
```

Comment: Language basics are covered in the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 1):

Methods defined for a type `T` are defined for both `T` and `*T`. Method defined for a type `*T` are only defined for `*T` and not for `T`.

The way it is defined, `*THelloWorld` implements `IRemoteFunction`, but not `THellowWorld`. Your program uses `THelloWorld`.

Here:

```
    t := reflect.TypeOf((*THelloWorld)(nil)).Elem()
```

By calling `Elem`, you get a `reflect.Type` for `THelloWorld`. Remove `Elem()` from this call, and it should work.

Comment: thank you . but  reflect.New(objectmap[strings.ToLower("test")]).Elem().Interface() is nil ,how to make instance ?

Comment: Make sure you're dealing with the correct types: `    objinf:=reflect.New(objectmap[strings.ToLower("test")].Elem()).Interface()
`

Comment: My design is to create different objects through strings to execute related methods, so I define an interface, and then execute the method through the interface, and return the result. In this way, when new functions are added, I only need to add new objects and register them through strings. Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: You can use a map of functions. Call the function to get an instance.

Comment: The map function has created an instance in advance, and I hope to create it at runtime. Do you have any relevant example code that I can learn from? Or some good articles?

Comment: No, use `var funcRegistry map[string]func() IRemoteFunction`, and then `newInstance:=funcRegistry["type"]()`. Use `init()` functions to populate the map. This is  a common pattern in stdlib as well.